# request module in python library gives status code as 200 when the browser gives 404

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-404

[Broswer shows page not found but request module gives 200 as status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuHDG.png)

```
In[23]:  requests.get("http://abc.us.gib.com/tool/cluster.jsp")
Out[23]: <Response [200]>
In[24]:  requests.get("http://abc.us.gib.com/tool/cluster.jsphttp://abc.us.gib.com/tool/cluster.jsp")
Out[24]: <Response [200]>
```

Given Two URL, the browser works fine for the first URL but gives error for the second one which it should but while checking the same with the python request module it gives 200 as status code for the both.
Attached image for reference.

**YOU won't be able to open the URL as it is not accessible outside.**

Comment: http://abc.us.gib.com/tool/cluster.jsphttp://abc.us.gib.com/tool/cluster.jsp isn't valid URL, request raise an exception for me

Comment: Yes..you won't able to access the URL as it required VPN connection to specific server.

Comment: Get function requires a valid url https://kite.com/python/docs/requests.get

Comment: the url is valid, it's just it's not accessible outside my network

Answer (score 0):

The site "http://abc.us.gib.com/tool/cluster.jsphttp://abc.us.gib.com/tool/cluster.jsp" returns wrong status code. Requests module works fine. You can check in a browser what status code above site returns.

Comment: yes, status code return by request module is wrong but can you please tell why status code is giving wrong status code ?

Comment: Maybe its due to the User-Agent or cookies that are set. You can try chaning the User agent and adding the cookies in the request. It should be indistinguishable for the webserver wheather youre calling the website from python or from a browser.